# Coordinate geometry, finding the locus of a point. Is the solution in the text book incorrect?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I spent some time on this question earlier today - the most difficult part was understanding the language used in the question and being able to visualise the point stated in the question as a point in the plane. After some wrestling I have managed to get an answer similar to the text but I appear to out by a factor of two, i.e. my solution is half of that quoted in the text. I'll stop waffling and give you the question, apologies for my lack of a diagram and if my algebra isn't perfect.

Question is as follows:

The equations of the sides of a rectangle are $x=0$, $x=2a$, $y=0$ and $y=a$. A point moves so that the sum of the squares of its distances from the sides of the rectangle is $k$, a constant. Show that the path of the point is a circle and find the coordinates of its centre.

If the radius of the circle is $5a$, find $k$.

Solution gives: $(a,\frac{a}{2})$ and $k=105a^2$

My working is as follows and apologies once again for lack of a diagram.

Let $P(\alpha,\beta)$ be a point on the locus.

Then we have:
$$(\alpha-2a)^2+\alpha^2+(\beta-a)^2+\beta^2=k$$
$$\implies 2\alpha^2+2\beta^2-4a\alpha-2a\beta+4a^2+a^2-k=0$$
$$\implies\alpha^2+\beta^2-2a\alpha-a\beta+\frac{5a^2}{2}-\frac{k}{2}=0\qquad(1)$$

This has the general form of a circle i.e., $\alpha^2+\beta^2+2f\alpha+2g\beta+c=0$ with centre $(-f,-g)$ and radius, $$r=\sqrt{f^2+g^2-c}\qquad(2)$$

Therefore, as $x=\alpha,\text{and},\ y=\beta$, equation of circle is:
$$x^2+y^2-2ax-ay+\frac{5a^2}{2}-\frac{k}{2}=0$$
$$\therefore\quad\text{locus is a circle with centre at}(a,\frac{a}{2})$$
$$\text {and radius},r=\sqrt{a^2+(\frac{a}{2})^2-\frac{5a^2}{2}+\frac{k}{2}}$$

Now, when $r=5a$, we have:
$$25a^2=\frac{5a^2}{4}-\frac{5a^2}{2}+\frac{k}{2}$$
$$\implies100a^2=-5a^2+2k$$
$$\therefore\qquad k=\frac{105a^2}{2}$$

I hope the above is clear and there are no errors in the algebra. If anyone can offer any advice with regards to whether or not my solution is correct then I would be very grateful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick check: the centre is at $\left(a, \frac a2\right)$ and the radius is $5a$, so $\left(6a, \frac a2\right)$ is on the circle, so $k$ from that point is

$$(6a-0)^2 + (6a-2a)^2 + \left(\frac a2-0\right)^2 + \left(\frac a2 - a\right)^2 = \left(36+16+\frac 14+\frac14\right)a^2$$

Comment: I never even thought of that; I get to the stage where I can't see the wood for the trees! Many thanks for clearing that up for me.